# Loop in multiple Threads

Tags: java

right now i'm trying to get my head arround threads and concurrency,
so i tried to make multiple threads which counts together to 1000.
Example: Thread 1=0, Thread 2=1.Thread 3=2, and so on
As you will see in the code i implemented the Runnable interface and started the threads.
What i can see is that every thread starts the loop only for itself even if i use a synchronized method.
This is the loop "class"

```
 private String threadname;
    private int counter;

    Task3(String threadname,int counter) {
        this.threadname = threadname;
        this.counter =counter;

    }

    private synchronized void compute(int i) {
    try {

        // "simulate" computation
        System.out.println(threadname);
        Thread.sleep(100);
        System.out.println(" " + i);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i <= counter;i++)
            compute(i);
    }
```

and in this class i start 4 threads with a for loop and give the method aboce the parameters which is only the thread name and how often they should count...

```
for(int i=0; i<=3;i++){
        Runnable r =new Thread(new Task3("Thread"+i,1000));
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: And what exactly are you asking ? I see no question in this post

Comment: I think that you are not following the approach you want. You are creating 4 instances (not 3, check for loop) of Task3 but you only want to create 1 instance and execute it in multiple threads, you can get the thread name with `Thead.currentThread().getName()`

Comment: if or how is it possible to create threads which count together to 1000

Comment: `synchronized` works on the object *instance*, i.e. the `this` value. You're creating 3 different objects, so the 3 threads are synchronizing on 3 different monitors, and hence no synchronization is happening.

Comment: Thank you @nachokk, i think you helped me, i will try it.
If I understand you right Andreas, sync... is for the whole instance of the class not for single methods?
So i have to create only one instance of the class and use 3 or more threads?

Comment: Why are you wrapping a `Thread` in a `Thread`? You're doing `new Thread()` twice.

Comment: @Andreas
I probably overlooked this issue, I'm trying it for hours now and I'm tired...
Thanks for mention it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

`Synchronized` only means that it is ensured that a thread **waits** before entering the method until another thread has **finished** executing this method. This means that **only one thread**, at one time, can be **inside of** this `synchronized` method.

This can prevent *strange behavior* when using non-atomic operations. For example threads catching outdated values, thinking they would be up-to-date.

---

### Solution

If you want that all threads count together you need some kind of **shared resource**, i.e. the counter. Currently every thread has his **own counter**. You need **one counter in total** which is **shared** among all threads.

A **quick and dirty** method would be to make the counter `static`. But you can probably do better with a design like this:

Class which manages the threads:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Counter counter = new Counter(demo, 1000);
            counter.start();
        }
    }

    // Provide a shared resource for all threads
    private int sharedCounter = 0;

    // Provide a count method for all threads
    // which is synchronized to ensure that no
    // strange behavior with non-atomic operations occurs
    public synchronized void count() {
        sharedCounter++;
    }
}
```

And the `Thread` class:

```
public class Counter extends Thread {
    private Demo mDemo;
    private int mAmount;

    public Counter(Demo demo, int amount) {
        // Remember the shared resource
        mDemo = demo;
        mAmount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i < 0; i < mAmount; i++) {
            // Call the count method provided
            // by the shared resource
            mDemo.count();

            // Sleep some millis
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I understood you right, if a method is synchronized only one thread can access it, so the other threads can't change anything and have to wait until the one who's accessing the method is finished.

Is there a big difference between extending Thread or implementing Runnable?

Because you inherit in this example the thread class?

Comment: Yes, if a thread already is inside a `synchronized` method others will **automatically wait** until it has finished. Well, if `Runnable` is possible for you (and it is here) then you should choose it in favor of `Thread` as `Runnable` simply is far more flexible. A `Runnable` object itself does only describe the task but not how it should get executed. A `Thread` describes how tasks, i.e. `Runnable` get executed but there are also other variants to execute `Runnable`, automated pools of threads for example, or remote machines.